# Multiline inputdialog

Tags: vim, input

I often want to insert in an input dialog multiple lines of text.

The inputdialog in vim has only a 1 line input box.
Does anyone know how to create a multiline input dialog box?

Comment: Your current window is a giant input dialog. Could you you explain what you are trying to do and *why* you are using input dialog in the first place?

Comment: Hi Romainl, I use the input dialog in functions. Yesterday I had a text where I had to insert 3 lines of text above every match I had from the search.

Comment: `inputdialog()` is a single line I'm afraid. But you could try to use `\n` and format the input afterwards.

Comment: I can do that in my Mac using option enter. Only one line is visible, but multiple lines are inserted. I'm not posting it as answer since I don't really know if you're on a Mac too, and I don't know any alternatives for that in other systems. If that's the case you may try a similar key combination.

Comment: @sidyll, it doesn't work in windows. If I select multiple lines of text and put it in a inputdialog, only the 1st line is inserted.

Comment: You didn't do what @sidyll suggested.

Comment: Re-reading now, I see I wasn't clear enough probably, but I mean when you are in the input field, write the first line, press option+enter and then it inserts the return character and starts a second line, even though the first isn't visible anymore it stills there.

Comment: @sidyll, there is no option key in windows (i.m.o.), however I found another way to do it: Paste the 1st line, add `\r`, Paste the 2nd line etc.. this is not a very nice solution however. I would like to have a multiline input dialog. :)

Comment: @Remonn I see. It's maybe equivalent to alt key? Sorry, I didn't know exactly about it indeed. Well, I don't think it's possible without changing the GUI itself… I also don't know which one you're using, but maybe you should consider patching it, or suggesting to the developers. It's designed like that to provide simple prompts anyway, where you answer, press enter and done.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, but it is possible that there are simpler alternatives. The global command (see `:h :global`) can be used to change text surrounding a match. Another possibility is passing a range to your function -- if you don't like passing line numbers, you can visually select your input lines on a regular buffer and use the visual selections marks `'<` and `'>`.